# Simulate an arrival time - Cox Process?

Tags: poisson-process, interarrival-time

If I simulate arrival times using a Poisson process where the input to the Poisson process is also a Poisson process.

Input arrival rate = L
, and then U1 and U2 are random draws from a uniform distribution

Simulated arrival rate = 1/ (-LN(U2)/L) =f ,
Arrival time = -LN(U1)/f ,
So then: 
Arrival time = -LN(U1)*(-LN(U2)/L)

This has quite nice feature that still only one input L and arrival time average will be 1/L but the arrival times will have more dispersion than a Poisson simulated arrival time.

Question: Is this a Cox process?

Comment: Could you modify the math parts by using MathJax?

Comment: Apologies have not used